# easy_install M2Crypto failing on Windows platform

Tags: windows, openssl, easy-install, m2crypto

I am attempting to install M2Crypto on a Windows XP platform.  I have Python, easy_install and SWIG installed, but when I attempt to `easy_install M2Crypto` I get the following:

```
SWIG\_m2crypto.i(31) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\opensslv.h'
SWIG\_m2crypto.i(45) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\safestack.h'
SWIG\_evp.i(12) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\opensslconf.h'
SWIG\_ec.i(7) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\opensslconf.h'
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'swig.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

I have read elsewhere that people have suggested `easy_install openssl-devel`, but that simply tells me that there are no packages found with that name.  Is the name perhaps case-sensitive (I've tried various permutations without success), or does that advice not apply to Windows?

I'm not looking for alternatives to M2Crypto.  I am picking up some existing code that uses it, so I need to get my development environment to be able to run what's already written.

Comment: I should also mention that this is Python 2.7.

Comment: You can also download and install a precompiled version of M2Crypto from here : http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a similar problem. After downloading the source package of M2Crypto and reading the INSTALL file I found the following:

```
Differences when installing on Windows
--------------------------------------

Before building from source, you need to install OpenSSL's include files,
import libraries and DLLs. By default setup.py assumes that OpenSSL include
files are in ``c:\pkg\openssl\include``, and the import libraries 
in ``c:\pkg\openssl\lib``. As with other platforms, you can specify a different
OpenSSL location with --openssl option to build_ext command.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I haven't had chance to check this out yet because I ended up setting up a dev environment on a non-Windows box.  But I shall give it a go when I have time.

Answer (score 8):

As jay stated in his answer you should try to build it from source. And I tried. The `setup.py` does not recognize the `--openssl` option. Looking at the output from the default `setup.py` I realized that the search location was `c:\pkg` and not `c:\pkg\openssl`.
The solution:

1. Download and install OpenSSL from [Win32 OpenSSL](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)
2. Copy the `lib` and `include` folders to `c:\pkg`
3. Check that `swig.exe` is available in your path
4. Run `easy_install M2Crypto`

Worked for me like a charm.