# How to Install M2crypto on Windows

Tags: python, windows, openssl, swig, m2crypto

After [installing OpenSSL](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), downloading the [pre-built Swig executable](http://www.swig.org/download.html), and ensuring the [openssl libraries are located in the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436771/easy-install-m2crypto-failing-on-windows-platform) `c:\pkg`, `pip install m2crypto` results in:

```
...
C:\Program Files (x86)\gfortran\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Pyth
on27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -Ic:\pkg\include -Ic:\users\evbo\appdata\local\tem
p\pip_build_evbo\m2crypto\SWIG -c SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\
Release\swig\_m2crypto_wrap.o -DTHREADING

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems the [binary installer solution for M2crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078493/installing-m2crypto-on-windows) is no longer available and I don't see any mistakes I've made based on the [M2crypto install doc](https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto/blob/master/INSTALL).

How might I resolve this install issue? Is there a dependency on older versions of GCC?

Comment: *"Are there any succint instructions for how to install M2crypto?"* - that's probably going to get the question closed. You have to find your own offsite resources.

Comment: @jww thanks, I clarified my answer to focus specifically on the install issue I'm having

Comment: You might try setting the path. Open a command prompt, and then `set PATH=c:\pkg\include\openssl;%PATH%`. Windows also uses `INCLUDE`, so you might also `set INCLUDE=c:\pkg\include\openssl`. That's assumming a header is located at `c:\pkg\include\openssl\include\openssl\opensslv.h`. Note: I had a problem once with the double `include\openssl`. So you might change the directory to `c:\pkg\include\openssl-xxx`.

Comment: The best I've found so far is this tutorial -http://www.gooli.org/blog/building-m2crypto-on-windows/ although there's supposedly a Windows build on the Project Chandler site (http://chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto), but it's down right now.

Comment: @jww thanks but actually openssl expects the libraries to be in a hard-coded location unless you build it yourself (default is `c:\pkg`) and yes @MikeDriscoll, I too would prefer an installer... when it comes back online!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got lucky - there's an unofficial binary installer in lieu of [chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto](http://chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto) being down:

https://github.com/saltstack/salt-windows-install/blob/master/deps/win32-py2.7/M2Crypto-0.21.1.win32-py2.7.msi

Comment: In case it's not obvious, you have to click "Raw" to download the actual installer.

Comment: I got the same issue, but installing that .msi didn't fix it

Comment: @Frederic The issue I was having involved installing M2Crypto, which the .msi is quite robust at ensuring success with. In other words, there is no need to run `pip install m2crypto` after running the .msi file.

Comment: Very nice find.  It makes installing offline easy.  Thanks for posting.  I wonder what the best way to vet the binaries installed by this msi are?

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on the GitHub comment at https://github.com/iOSForensics/pymobiledevice/issues/25#issuecomment-576119104, for a Python module that requires `m2crypto`.

Some builds for `m2crypto` for specific versions of Python are available from their CI: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/m2crypto/m2crypto/history. Try selecting a version, selecting a job that matches your Python version, then going to the "Artifacts" tab and downloading an installer. To install a `.whl` file, see step 11 of my build tutorial below.

[M2Crypto-0.35.2.win-amd64-py3.8.zip](https://github.com/iOSForensics/pymobiledevice/files/4084638/M2Crypto-0.35.2.win-amd64-py3.8.zip) is the `m2crypto` module that I have built on Windows 10 x64, Python 3.8.1. It should work on any x64-based version of Windows with any version of Python 3.8.X.

However, if you are unable to find a build that matches your Python version and system type and architecture, you may need to manually build `m2crypto`. I adapted the build steps from their CI build scripts: https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/blob/master/appveyor.yml. I built the module by doing the following:

1. Install the latest `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019`. See https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ under "All Downloads" -> "Tools for Visual Studio 2019". This direct link was active as of this writing: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16
2. In the installer, select "C++ Build Tools", install, and reboot if necessary.
3. Install the latest full (not `Light`) `OpenSSL` for your architecture (`Win64`/`Win32`). Current version as of this writing is `1.1.1d`. Make note of the directory to which you install `OpenSSL`. https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
4. In `PowerShell`, install the `Chocolatey` package manager. I used this command from their website: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`
5. Install `swig` with `Chocolatey` (in `PowerShell`). `choco install -r -y swig`
6. Install the `pywin32` dependency. Run `pip install pywin32`. If you have problems, try first running `pip install wheel`. To get `pip` to target a specific Python installation, try launching it using `py -[version] -m pip install [module]`. Note: you may need to use an elevated (administrator) `PowerShell` to install Python modules.
7. Get the latest `m2crypto` code. If you have `git` installed, run `git clone https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto`. Otherwise, download and extract the code from GitLab: https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/-/archive/master/m2crypto-master.zip
8. Use `cd` to change into the directory `m2crypto` was cloned/extracted to.
9. Assuming `python` launches your desired Python interpreter version, run `python setup.py build --openssl="C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64" --bundledlls`, replacing `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64` with the directory to which you installed `OpenSSL`. (On some systems you can use the `py` launcher to specify a Python version to use, run `py -h` for more information.)
10. Generate the installable files. `python.exe setup.py bdist_wheel bdist_wininst bdist_msi`.
11. Install the module. `cd` into the `dist` directory and run `pip install M2Crypto-0.35.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`, replacing the filename with the generated `.whl` file. If you have problems, try first running `pip install wheel`. To get `pip` to target a specific Python installation, try launching it using `py -[version] -m pip install [module]`. Alternatively, you can run the generated `.exe` or `.msi` installer. Note: you may need to use an elevated (administrator) `PowerShell` to install Python modules.

Comment: the first link is golden, just downloaded *M2Crypto-0.37.1.win-amd64-py3.7.msi* - it can be so easy

Comment: Note at the moment m2crypto doesnt support openssl 3 (e.g. https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/-/issues/302and others), so you need to install the latest v1.1.1, i.e. v1.1.1L at the moment.

Comment: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/m2crypto/m2crypto/history builds have been failing, and artifacts are only kept for one month now, so the first suggestion doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

The https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto project provides Windows builds of M2Crypto.

You can find wheels for current Python versions from their AppVeyor builds at https://ci.appveyor.com/project/m2crypto/m2crypto.

For example, to install M2Crypto 0.37.1 from https://ci.appveyor.com/project/m2crypto/m2crypto →
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/m2crypto/m2crypto/builds/37187357/job/5c56adinoe9l8kng/artifacts with `pip` for 64-bit Python 3.8, run:

```
pip install \
  https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/5c56adinoe9l8kng/artifacts/dist/M2Crypto-0.37.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

**NB!** The artifacts may expire in AppVeyor, see [this bug](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/issues/263) for updates.

Answer (score 1):

It's late 2019 and installing M2Crypto is still a pain! After a ton of Googling, finally got it down to the steps below:

```
pip install wheel
pip install M2CryptoWin32
```

Using a fresh Python 2.7.17 32bit install on Windows 10. You *might* need install http://aka.ms/vcpython27 first.

I'd imagine one should use M2CryptoWin64 instead if you've installed 64-bit Python.

Comment: M2CryptoWin32 & M2CryptoWin64 havent been updated since 2014, which will make them unsuitable for most.
When I tried M2CryptoWin64 on Python 3.7, the result was `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__m2crypto'`.
Still, the repos https://github.com/dsoprea/M2CryptoWin32 and https://github.com/dsoprea/M2CryptoWin64 might be a useful starting point for someone.

Answer (score 0):

in **windows**, (python versions 3.7 | 3.8 | 3.9 | 3.10) you can download *whl* file from [here](https://github.com/cperezabo/m2crypto-wheels) and install it with this command:

```
python install M2Crypto-0.38.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```

replace current *whl* file name.

Answer (score -1):

1~11: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59817750

12: install M2Crypto.whl and adb in one command

> pip install M2Crypto-0.38.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl adb

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).