# Unable to install M2Crypto package

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, pip, m2crypto

I am using Win7 64 bit machine with Python 2.7 installed. I have installed swigwin 3.0.5. When I do "pip install M2Crypto" I got the following errors:

```
SWIG\_m2crypto.i(30) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\opensslv.h'

SWIG\_m2crypto.i(33) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\safestack.h'

SWIG\_evp.i(12) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\opensslconf.h'

SWIG\_ec.i(7) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\opensslconf.h'
```

In some links I found the suggestion is to install openssl-dev. But I could not find the equivalent package for windows (pip install openssl-dev does not work and I have done pip install pyOpenSSL which did not help me).

Thanks in advance for your help in this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110774/how-to-install-m2crypto-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your OS is. But to solve the issue on MAC OS X Yosemite you need to reinitialise xcode command line tools by using this command in terminal.

xcode-select --install

This solved the problem for me.