# M2Crypto installation

Tags: m2crypto

I am struggling to get my M2Crypto installation to work

```
C:\Python27>python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from M2Crypto import RSA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\M2Crypto\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import __m2crypto
ImportError: No module named __m2crypto
>>>
```

Not really surprising as there is no __m2crypto module anywhere,  but where should it be and where should I get it from?

I have installed M2Crypto from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto by downloading M2Crypto-master and copying the unziped M2Crypto folder to c:\Python27\lib

From M2Crypto I only need the RSA functionality so suggestions involving alternatives to M2Crypto would also be helpful.

Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There pretty good instruction on building M2Crypto, I've using myself, here:
http://www.gooli.org/blog/building-m2crypto-on-windows/

> **Building M2Crypto for Windows**
>
> M2Crypto uses a tool called SWIG to help write the Python code that
>   wraps the OpenSSL library that is written in C, so we’ll have to
>   download and install it.
>
> Let’s go.
>
> 1. Download the latest SWIG Windows binaries from
>      http://www.swig.org/download.html .
> 2. Unzip and untar the SWIG package to some directory and add that
>      directory to your PATH.
> 3. Download the latest M2Crypto sources from
>      http://chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto.
> 4. Unzip and untar the M2Crypto source somewhere and open a command
>      prompt there.
> 5. > python setup.py build_ext –openssl c:/openssl
> 6. > python setup.py bdist_wininst
>
> That last command will create a nice M2Crypto-0.18.win32-py2.4.exe
>   file in the dist subdirectory which you can run to install M2Crypto in
>   the Python site-packages directory.
>
> To test your build, run python and do import M2Crypto. If you get an
>   error that says ‘ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 182′,
>   it’s because the M2Crypto library can’t find the OpenSSL DLLs. You’ll
>   need to place the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll files somewhere python
>   can find them. The directory in which your script resides is a good
>   bet.

If you still have problems with building, I'd recently compiled M2Crypto for my needs on Windows 7 x64 - Python 2.7 You can download binary here (M2Crypto-0.22.3.win32-py2.7.exe): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByAiJQIq8icYOUNiZEJQQzVhdVU/view?usp=sharing

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can install M2Crypto from the project AppVeyor builds, see detailed overview [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110774/how-to-install-m2crypto-on-windows).

For example, to install M2Crypto 0.37.1 with `pip` for 64-bit Python 3.8, run:

```
pip install \
  https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/5c56adinoe9l8kng/artifacts/dist/M2Crypto-0.37.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

**NB!** The artifacts may expire in AppVeyor, see [this bug](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/issues/263) for updates.