# pip install m2crypto error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, m2crypto

```
$sudo pip3 install m2crypto
Collecting m2crypto
  Using cached M2Crypto-0.26.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: typing in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from m2crypto)
Installing collected packages: m2crypto
  Running setup.py install for m2crypto ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ejd_4lk_/m2crypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ecxgdei0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    copying M2Crypto/BIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/DH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/Rand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/ftpslib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/m2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/m2xmlrpclib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/callback.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/EC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/m2urllib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/X509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/ASN1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/m2crypto.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/Err.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/SMIME.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/threading.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/m2urllib2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/BN.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/RC4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/Engine.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/six.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/EVP.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/httpslib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/AuthCookie.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/PublicKey.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/PublicKeyRing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/packet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/PGP
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/SSLServer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/TwistedProtocolWrapper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/ssl_dispatcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Checker.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/timeout.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Cipher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Context.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/cb.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Session.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/M2Crypto/SSL
    running build_ext
    building 'M2Crypto._m2crypto' extension
    swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
    swig -python -D__x86_64__ -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -includeall -modern -builtin -outdir /tmp/pip-build-ejd_4lk_/m2crypto/M2Crypto -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h:159: Warning 305: Bad constant value (ignored).
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wchar.h:38: Warning 490: Fragment 'SWIG_From_wchar_t' not found.
    /usr/include/stdint.h:274: Warning 490: Fragment 'SWIG_From_wchar_t' not found.
    SWIG/_bio.i:64: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_rand.i:23: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_evp.i:184: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_dh.i:36: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_rsa.i:43: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_dsa.i:31: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_ssl.i:237: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_ssl.i:238: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_x509.i:335: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_pkcs7.i:44: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_pkcs7.i:44: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_util.i:11: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_ec.i:111: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    SWIG/_engine.i:168: Warning 454: Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/SWIG
....
At top level:
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:3993:13: warning: ‘lock_count’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
     static long lock_count[CRYPTO_NUM_LOCKS];
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:3992:27: warning: ‘lock_cs’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
     static PyThread_type_lock lock_cs[CRYPTO_NUM_LOCKS];
                               ^~~~~~~
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
**`Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ejd_4lk_/m2crypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ecxgdei0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ejd_4lk_/m2crypto/`**
```

> > failed to install, when i tierd to install it got:
>
> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ```
>     ----------------------------------------
> **`Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ejd_4lk_/m2crypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
> ```
>
> 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-ecxgdei0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ejd_4lk_/m2crypto/`**
>
> ***> could someone help me please to fix this problem ?, thanks!***

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M2Crypto (as of version 0.26) does *not* officially support Python 3.
*Officially* supported Python versions are:

```
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
```

The issue you're having is same as described in  https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/issues/114#note_13223251

You can find out which popular libraries are compatible with Python 3 at http://py3readiness.org/

Answer (score 35):

We are able to use m2crypto on Python 3 with following global packages `libssl-dev swig python3-dev gcc`

so

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev swig python3-dev gcc
```

should allow install m2crypto via PIP for Python 3 (tested on version 0.32)

Comment: what would be the solution for the windows system.

Comment: This works for me. after doing that, i run the command: python3 -m pip install ...

Answer (score 8):

Steps in MAC for python3.X:

First Install.

`brew install openssl`

Second Swig

`brew install swig`

Change the SWIG_FEATURES

````
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
SWIG_FEATURES="-cpperraswarn -includeall -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
pip install m2crypto```
````

Comment: See also https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/-/blob/master/INSTALL.rst#macosx

Comment: I'm getting the following error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/stdint.h:123: Error: Unknown SWIG preprocessor directive: include_next (if this is a block of target language code, delimit it with %{ and %})
    error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Great answer... Fix to the point...

Answer (score 2):

I had this error on python 2.7.

This happens when the c dependencies for python aren't available and `pip` attempts to install and compile a package that has a c extension.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

This resolves it for me.

After this install `M2Crypto`

```
pip install m2crypto
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, this works 100%

```
apt install python2.7
python2.7 -m pip install M2Crypto
```

Answer (score 0):

for **windows** and python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 or 3.10 see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74974018/6463937) link

Answer (score 0):

On Mac do the following

```
$> brew install openssl
$> brew install swig
```

Now add these lines to your `~/.zshrc` file on Mac OS X

```
# this is very slow, see https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3327
# OPENSSL=$(brew --prefix openssl)
# this is much faster
# OPENSSL=$(dirname $(dirname $(which openssl)))
# hardcoding is fastest
OPENSSL=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1
export PATH="$OPENSSL/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L$OPENSSL/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$OPENSSL/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$OPENSSL/lib/pkgconfig"
export SWIG_FEATURES="-cpperraswarn -includeall -I$OPENSSL/include"
```

Then in a new terminal do

```
$> pip install m2crypto
```

see

- https://gist.github.com/asmaier/c0cc95a823264c90ce080754d5f5a68e